# r - copy missing values from other variables

Tags: r, missing-data

Simple question, but I can't figure out how to do the following. This is my data:

```
ID    Time1    Time2    Time3    Time4
01    23       23       NA       NA  
02    21       21       21       NA
03    22       22       25       NA
04    29       29       20       NA
05    NA       NA       15       22
06    NA       NA       11       NA
```

Now, I want to replace missing values (NA) with the data that is available in other variables. Importantly, I need r to take the value that is 'closest' to the missing data point. E.g., for ID 5, Time1 and Time2 should be "15" (not "22").

Like this:

```
ID    Time1    Time2    Time3    Time4
01    23       23       23       23  
02    21       21       21       21
03    22       22       25       25
04    29       29       20       20
05    15       15       15       22
06    11       11       11       11
```

I've tried ifelse statements, but this did not work out.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you break ties for "closest"? e.g. what if you have `Time1` and `Time3`, but not `Time2`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, very important indeed! The preferred order is from left to right (i.e., chronologically: Time1>Time2>Time3>Time4)

Comment: With "Time1" and "Time4" non-NA ("Time2" and "Time3" as NA) would "Time2" == "Time1" and "Time3" == "Time4"? Could you add any edge cases in your example and the way to be handled?

Comment: Yes exactly! So that each variable is matched with it's closest available value/time point. I.e., Time 2 == Time 1, Time 3 == Time 4

Comment: One way that would certainly be acceptable to me, is starting with Time2 / match NA's with values from Time1, Time3 (match with Time 2), Time4 (match with Time3). Than the other way around (i.e. match Time3 with Time4 et cetera). Repeat until finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is much more difficult that it looks. I built a solution that works on one column at a time, taking the [`pmin()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extremes.html) of the absolute distance between all time column indexes and the current column index, stripping NAs with the `na.rm=T` argument. The result can then be used to index the original time columns using an index matrix, which can then be assigned to the current column index in the target data.frame.

An advantage of this design is that it's fully vectorized over the rows. In other words, it doesn't iterate over one row at a time. This could be an advantage for extremely row-heavy inputs. On the other hand, the solution does involve building matrices that parallel all time columns (`timemat`, `nacols`, and `off`), which could be expensive for large inputs. It's basically trading away memory to save CPU.

I added a couple of rows to test additional cases not covered by the OP's sample data.frame; specifically (1) an all-NA row, and (2) a row with candidate non-NA values on either side of NA values.

---

Input:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08'),Time1=c(23L,21L,22L,NA,29L,NA,NA,1L),Time2=c(23L,21L,22L,NA,29L,NA,NA,NA),Time3=c(NA,21L,25L,NA,20L,15L,11L,NA),Time4=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,22L,NA,2L),stringsAsFactors=F);
df;
##   ID Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4
## 1 01    23    23    NA    NA
## 2 02    21    21    21    NA
## 3 03    22    22    25    NA
## 4 04    NA    NA    NA    NA
## 5 05    29    29    20    NA
## 6 06    NA    NA    15    22
## 7 07    NA    NA    11    NA
## 8 08     1    NA    NA     2
```

Solution:

```
ris <- seq_len(nrow(df));
cis <- grep('^Time',names(df));
timemat <- as.matrix(df[cis]);
nacols <- as.data.frame(ifelse(is.na(timemat),NA,col(timemat)));
nacols;
##   Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4
## 1     1     2    NA    NA
## 2     1     2     3    NA
## 3     1     2     3    NA
## 4    NA    NA    NA    NA
## 5     1     2     3    NA
## 6    NA    NA     3     4
## 7    NA    NA     3    NA
## 8     1    NA    NA     4
for (ci in seq_len(ncol(timemat))) {
    off <- abs(nacols-ci);
    best <- which(off==do.call(pmin,c(off,na.rm=T)),arr.ind=T);
    df[cis[ci]] <- timemat[matrix(c(ris,best[match(ris,best[,'row']),'col']),nrow(df))];
};
df;
##   ID Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4
## 1 01    23    23    23    23
## 2 02    21    21    21    21
## 3 03    22    22    25    25
## 4 04    NA    NA    NA    NA
## 5 05    29    29    20    20
## 6 06    15    15    15    22
## 7 07    11    11    11    11
## 8 08     1     1     2     2
```

---

Rcpp solution:

```
library(Rcpp);
cppFunction('
    IntegerMatrix fillDFNAsWithNearestInRow(DataFrame df, IntegerVector cis ) {
        IntegerMatrix res(df.nrows(),cis.size());
        if (df.nrows()==0 || cis.size()==0) return res;
        IntegerVector cis0 = clone(cis); for (int cisi = 0; cisi < cis0.size(); ++cisi) --cis0[cisi]; // correct from R 1-based to Rcpp 0-based
        for (int cisi = 0; cisi < cis0.size(); ++cisi) {
            IntegerVector colCur = df[cis0[cisi]];
            for (int ri = 0; ri < colCur.size(); ++ri) {
                if (!IntegerVector::is_na(colCur[ri])) {
                    res(ri,cisi) = colCur[ri];
                    continue;
                }
                int leftOk;
                int rightOk;
                IntegerVector colLeft;
                IntegerVector colRight;
                bool set = false; // assumption
                for (int off = 1; (leftOk = cisi-off>=0, rightOk = cisi+off<cis0.size(), leftOk ) || rightOk; ++off) {
                    if (leftOk && (colLeft = df[cis0[cisi-off]], !IntegerVector::is_na(colLeft[ri]))) {
                        res(ri,cisi) = colLeft[ri];
                        set = true;
                        break;
                    } else if (rightOk && (colRight = df[cis0[cisi+off]], !IntegerVector::is_na(colRight[ri]))) {
                        res(ri,cisi) = colRight[ri];
                        set = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!set) res(ri,cisi) = NA_INTEGER;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
');
```

---

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08'),Time1=c(23L,21L,22L,NA,29L,NA,NA,1L),Time2=c(23L,21L,22L,NA,29L,NA,NA,NA),Time3=c(NA,21L,25L,NA,20L,15L,11L,NA),Time4=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,22L,NA,2L),stringsAsFactors=F);
cis <- grep('^Time',names(df));
df[cis] <- fillDFNAsWithNearestInRow(df,cis);
df;
##   ID Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4
## 1 01    23    23    23    23
## 2 02    21    21    21    21
## 3 03    22    22    25    25
## 4 04    NA    NA    NA    NA
## 5 05    29    29    20    20
## 6 06    15    15    15    22
## 7 07    11    11    11    11
## 8 08     1     1     2     2
```

Comment: Thanks so much. 

Sorry to bother you again, but do you think that this is adaptable so that this works with different groups of variables? That is, I have 
Time1_A Time2_A Time3_A Time4_A  Time1_B Time2_B Time3_B Time4_BTime1_C   
Et cetera

So I want NA's to be replaced within groups of variables, but obviously not between them ("B" variable values are not suitable replacements for "A" variables")

Comment: Yes, you can assign `cis` to the subset of column indexes that you want to perform the filling-in for. If there are multiple groups, you can run the code multiple times, with different `cis` values each time.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks so much, most helpful response ever!

Answer (score 4):

With data.table's rolling joins and `set`:

```
library(data.table)
good = as.data.table( which(!is.na(df[-1]), arr.ind = TRUE) )
all = CJ(row = seq(nrow(df)), col = seq(2L, ncol(df)))
good$col = good$col + 1L
good$col_src = good$col

changes = good[all, on = c("row", "col"), roll="nearest"][ col != col_src ]

changes[, {
  set(df, i = row, j = col, value = df[[ col_src ]][row])
  NULL
}, by=.(col,col_src)]

# based on input from bgoldst's answer
   ID  1  2  3  4
1: 01 23 23 23 23
2: 02 21 21 21 21
3: 03 22 22 25 25
4: 04 NA NA NA NA
5: 05 29 29 20 20
6: 06 15 15 15 22
7: 07 11 11 11 11
8: 08  1  1  2  2
```

We find all entries to switch and then modify by reference with `set`. I'm not sure how `roll="nearest"` handles ties, but I'm sure that can be tweaked.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Yet another attempt. Breaking down as much as possible: (1) loop once from left to right carrying the last non-NA value forward and, also, recording where was the non-NA the replaced each NA, (2) loop again from right to left (a) replacing NAs carrying non-NAs backwards and (b) comparing the distance of the non-NA tha replaced each NA to the current non-NA and either keep or replace. Despite the two explicit loops, the computations involve vectors of `length == nrow(x)`.

```
ff = function(x)
{    
    taken_from = lapply(seq_along(x), rep_len, nrow(x))
    nas = lapply(x, is.na)

    #loop left -> right 
    # carry forward non-NAs and record which non-NA replaced NA
    last_nona = !nas[[1L]]
    for(j in 2:length(x)) {
        i = which(nas[[j]] & last_nona)
        x[[j]][i] = x[[j - 1L]][i]
        taken_from[[j]][i] = taken_from[[j - 1L]][i]
        last_nona = !is.na(x[[j]])
    }

    #loop right -> left
    #if NA and not replace carry the previous non-NA backward
    #else compare which non-NA is nearer and replace appropriately
    last_nona = !nas[[length(x)]]
    for(j in (length(x) - 1L):1L) {
        i1 = which(nas[[j]] & last_nona)
        i = i1[(j - taken_from[[j]][i1]) > (taken_from[[(j + 1L)]][i1] - j)]
        ii = i1[j == taken_from[[j]][i1]]
        taken_from[[j]][i] = taken_from[[j + 1L]][i]
        taken_from[[j]][ii] = taken_from[[j + 1L]][ii]
        x[[j]][i] = x[[j + 1L]][i]
        x[[j]][ii] = x[[j + 1L]][ii]
        last_nona = !is.na(x[[j]])
    }

    return(x)
}
```

Using bgoldst's data:

```
ff(df[-1L])
#  Time1 Time2 Time3 Time4
#1    23    23    23    23
#2    21    21    21    21
#3    22    22    25    25
#4    NA    NA    NA    NA
#5    29    29    20    20
#6    15    15    15    22
#7    11    11    11    11
#8     1     1     2     2
```

And the neccessary benchmarking:

```
set.seed(911)            
DAT = as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, 0:10), 1e7, TRUE), 1e6, 10))
system.time({ ansff = ff(DAT) })
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.82    0.38    1.75 
system.time({ ansbgoldst1 = bgoldst1(DAT) })
#   user  system elapsed 
#  20.96    7.53   42.04 
system.time({ ansbgoldst2 = bgoldst2(DAT) })
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.97    0.25    1.64 
sf1 = system.time({ ansfrank = frank(DAT) }); sf2 = system.time( copy(DAT) )
sf1 - sf2
#   user  system elapsed 
#   5.84    1.46    8.59 
all.equal(ansff, ansbgoldst1)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(ansbgoldst1, ansbgoldst2)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(ansbgoldst2, ansfrank)
#[1] TRUE
```

the functions:

```
bgoldst1 = function(x)
{
    ris = seq_len(nrow(x))
    xm = as.matrix(x)
    nacols = as.data.frame(lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) { x[[i]][!is.na(x[[i]])] = i; x[[i]] }))
    for(ci in seq_along(x)) {
        off = abs(nacols - ci)
        best = which(off == do.call(pmin, c(off, na.rm = TRUE)), arr.ind = TRUE)
        x[ci] = xm[matrix(c(ris, best[match(ris, best[, "row"]), "col"]), nrow(x))]
    }
    x
}

bgoldst2 = function(x) 
{
    ans = as.data.frame(fillDFNAsWithNearestInRow(x, seq_along(x)))
    names(ans) = names(x)
    ans
}

frank = function(x)
{
    x = copy(x)
    good = as.data.table(which(!is.na(x), arr.ind = TRUE))
    all = CJ(row = seq_len(nrow(x)), col = seq_len(ncol(x)))
    good$col = good$col
    good$col_src = good$col

    changes = good[all, on = c("row", "col"), roll = "nearest"][col != col_src]

    changes[, {
            set(x, i = row, j = col, value = x[[col_src]][row])
            NULL
            }, by = .(col, col_src)]
    x
}
```

Comment: @bgoldst : I see the opposite; with "DAT" from above and `mDAT = as.matrix(DAT)`, I get `system.time({ nacols1 = as.data.frame(ifelse(is.na(mDAT), NA, col(mDAT))) })` --> elapsed 1.16 and `system.time({ nacols2 = as.data.frame(lapply(seq_along(DAT), function(i) { DAT[[i]][!is.na(DAT[[i]])] = i; DAT[[i]] })) })` --> elapsed 0.15. I, honestly, made the change, at first, to avoid creating another large `col(x)` and to replace the `ifelse(is.na(..` with explicit `"["`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
x <-read.table(text="ID    Time1    Time2    Time3    Time4
01    23       23       NA       NA  
02    21       21       21       NA
03    22       22       25       NA
04    29       29       20       NA
05    NA       NA       15       22
06    NA       NA       11       NA", header=TRUE)

x <- as.matrix(x[,-1])

dofill <- function(r){
  PREV <- c(NA, suppressWarnings(head(r, -1)))
  NEXT <- c(tail(r,-1), NA)
  r[is.na(r)] <- PREV[is.na(r)]
  r[is.na(r)] <- NEXT[is.na(r)]
  r
}

rlefill <- function(r){
  r[is.na(r)] <- "NA"
  rle1 <- rle(r)
  rle1$values <- dofill(as.numeric(rle1$values))
  inverse.rle(rle1)
}

t(apply(x, 1, rlefill))
```

`dofill`  simply replaces all NA's with the previous value, and all remaining NA's with next values.

`rlefill` is needed to transform a sequence of NA's into "one big NA".

Of course, if you have a larger number of time points, you may need something like ...

```
cis <- grep('^Time',names(df))
timemat <- as.matrix(df[cis]);
```

... i.e. a more universal solution of extracting the relevant part from the data frame.

(Now I realize that this is not exactly what you asked - my solution always uses the preceding value if it is available, even if the following value is closer in time. It doesn't make a difference in your example data set but it may make difference in real data.)