# Populate the missing values from a variable with values from the closest point in time, in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, time-series

I have data which looks like this (but for 14 million people)

It is each person's value for MB in a given quarter (qtr). If qtr == 20091001, it is the period from October to December 2009.

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(c('ABC1234', 'CED6723', 'GHB9876', "MNR4444", "FRE9823"), 4),
  qtr = c(rep('20090101', 5), rep('20090401', 5),rep('20090701', 5),rep('20091001', 5)),
  MB = c('0000000', "1234567", "5678910", "1234567", 
         "9384756", "3456789", NA, '0000000',
         "7394857", '0000000', '0000000', '0000000',
         "9485967", "9485967", "9485967", '0000000',
         '0000000', NA, '4545455', '1987656'
         )
)
```

What I want to do is replace the value of MB where it is NA or == '0000000' with the most recent value of MB.

The rules would be:
If MB is NA or 0 in 20091001, I want the value to come from 20090701 (if populated), then 20090401 (if populated), then 20090101.

If MB is NA or 0 in 20090701, I want the value to come from 20090401 (if populated), then 20090101 (if populated), then 20091001.

If MB is NA or 0 in 20090401, I want the value to come from 20090101 (if populated), then 20090701 (if populated), then 20091001.

If MB is NA or 0 in 20090101, I want the value to come from 20090401 (if populated), then 20090701 (if populated), then 20091001.

My ideal output looks like this

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(c('ABC1234', 'CED6723', 'GHB9876', "MNR4444", "FRE9823"), 4),
  qtr = c(rep('20090101', 5), rep('20090401', 5),rep('20090701', 5),rep('20091001', 5)),
  MB = c("1234567", "1234567", "5678910", "1234567", 
         "9384756", "3456789", "3456789", "3456789",
         "7394857", "7394857", "7394857", "7394857",
         "9485967", "9485967", "9485967", "9485967",
         '4545455', '4545455', '4545455', '1987656'
  )
)
```

I have seen this response [r - copy missing values from other variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724309/r-copy-missing-values-from-other-variables) 
This is for data which is in wide format. Do I need to convert my data to wide format, and change the labels of the qtr variable to 1, 2, 3, 4 ? Or is there a way to do this on my dataframe as it is?

Thanks.

Comment: Based on your description, it sounds like you are pulling data from both the past (if available) and the future.  Is this intended?

Comment: Do you want to do this for each `ID` ?

Comment: Yes, pull data from the future if the past is not available. Yes, I would like to do it for any ID where there is an NA or  value for any of the quarters. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So you can do that by using tidyr function fill, but first I checked if the value is zeros then I made it NA because fill focuses on NA values only as follows;

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Creating dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(c('ABC1234', 'CED6723', 'GHB9876', "MNR4444", "FRE9823"), 4),
  qtr = c(rep('20090101', 5), rep('20090401', 5),rep('20090701', 5),rep('20091001', 5)),
  MB = c('0000000', "1234567", "5678910", "1234567", 
         "9384756", "3456789", NA, '0000000',
         "7394857", '0000000', '0000000', '0000000',
         "9485967", "9485967", "9485967", '0000000',
         '0000000', NA, '4545455', '1987656'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df2 <-
  df %>%
  # If MB is zeros then convert it into NA
  mutate(MB = ifelse(as.numeric(MB) == 0, NA_character_, MB)) %>%
  # Fill automatically fills NA data with closest values
  # given the direction of the filling
  # you can change the direction as you like
  # To know more about it ?fill
  fill(MB, .direction = "downup")

df2

# ID      qtr      MB
# ABC1234 20090101 1234567
# CED6723 20090101 1234567
# GHB9876 20090101 5678910
# MNR4444 20090101 1234567
# FRE9823 20090101 9384756
# ABC1234 20090401 3456789
# CED6723 20090401 3456789
# GHB9876 20090401 3456789
# MNR4444 20090401 7394857
# FRE9823 20090401 7394857
```

Comment: I think you need to add a `group_by(ID)` to make the fill specific to the individual.

Comment: @Ronak actually you are correct and the output is far from the expected output. I think the idea is not for each ID. I dropped the group_by line of code.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `zoo::na.locf` assuming the data is ordered by `qtr` as shown in the shared data.

```
df$MB <- as.numeric(as.character(df$MB))
df$MB <- replace(df$MB, df$MB == 0, NA)
df$MB <- zoo::na.locf(df$MB, fromLast = TRUE)

df
#        ID      qtr      MB
#1  ABC1234 20090101 1234567
#2  CED6723 20090101 1234567
#3  GHB9876 20090101 5678910
#4  MNR4444 20090101 1234567
#5  FRE9823 20090101 9384756
#6  ABC1234 20090401 3456789
#7  CED6723 20090401 7394857
#8  GHB9876 20090401 7394857
#9  MNR4444 20090401 7394857
#10 FRE9823 20090401 9485967
#11 ABC1234 20090701 9485967
#12 CED6723 20090701 9485967
#13 GHB9876 20090701 9485967
#14 MNR4444 20090701 9485967
#15 FRE9823 20090701 9485967
#16 ABC1234 20091001 4545455
#17 CED6723 20091001 4545455
#18 GHB9876 20091001 4545455
#19 MNR4444 20091001 4545455
#20 FRE9823 20091001 1987656
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. This doesn't appear to work on my larger dataset. I don't think the code makes it explicit to the individual. So one person's information is being added onto another person's. Is there a way to alter this code so that the missing value is only ever replaced when the ID values match?

Comment: @Laura your expected output doesn't show this has to be applied by `ID`. For example, for `ID` "ABC1234" how do you get `MB` values as `1234567`. There is no value for that `ID` before it.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak. For the ID ABC1234, I would want the value of MB to come from later in time. So we look backward in time first, but if there is no suitable match, then we start looking forward in time. Is that possible?

Comment: @Laura If you look later in time for ID ABC1234 the later value is 3456789 and not 1234567. You can try `df %>%
  mutate(MB = as.numeric(as.character(MB)), 
         MB = replace(MB, MB == 0, NA)) %>%
  arrange(ID, qtr) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  fill(MB, .direction = "updown")`